# Generic problem with List

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to make a Parallel Helper class (`ParallelRunner`) that can be used like in the `RequestService` class:

```
public class ParallelFunction
{
    public ParallelFunction(Func<object> function)
    {
        Function = function;
    }

    public T GetResult<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (T) Data;
    }

    public Func<object> Function { get; private set; }
    public object Data { private get; set; }
}

public static class ParallelRunner
{
    public static void Run( IEnumerable<ParallelFunction> parallelFunctions)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(parallelFunctions, f =>{f.Data = f.Function();});
    }
}


public class RequestService
{
    public void DoParallel()
    {
        var da = new RequestDataAccess();
        var pf1 = new ParallelFunction(da.GetRequests);
        var pf2 = new ParallelFunction(da.GetRequestAnswers);

        ParallelRunner.Run(new List<ParallelFunction> { pf1, pf2 });

        var requests = pf1.GetResult<List<Request>>();
        var answers = pf2.GetResult<List<RequestAnswer>>();
    }
}
```

what I really would love to have was a generic ParallelFunction Class like that:

```
public class ParallelFunction<T>  where T : class
{
    public ParallelFunction(Func<T> function)
    {
        Function = function;
    }

    public Func<T> Function { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

And instead of getting the Data From the `GetResult<T>` that does a cast of the desired type, getting the Data from the `T Data` property.

The problem is here `ParallelRunner.Run(new List<ParallelFunction> { pf1, pf2 });` if ParallelFunction is with the generic i'm of course not able to add tow different types into the list.

Maybe someone have a good idea how to solve that?

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is directly possible, you could have some kind of ParallelFunction interface that the generic class implements, but then to access the actual typed Data property you would have still have to do casting from the interface to ParallelFunction<T>. Maybe you could implement a visitor pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN such situations where generic types are exposed to non-generic infrastructure, I introduce an interface that is non-generic:

```
public class ParallelFunction<T> : IParallelFunction
{
    private readonly Func<T> function;

    public ParallelFunction(Func<T> function)
    {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public void CacheResult()
    {
        Data = function();
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}
```

You see, I changed the design a bit to expose less of the stuff that the class does. The interface can expose non-generic bits "CacheResult". Your Helper can now work off the interface by invoking the Cacheresult method. Outside the helper you can still have your generic implementations.

```
public static class ParallelRunner
{
    public static void Run(IEnumerable<IParallelFunction> parallelFunctions)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(parallelFunctions, f => f.CacheResult());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variant generic interface `IParallelFunc<out T>` that `ParallelFunc<T>` implements. Then, a `IParallelFunc<int>` and a `IParallelFunc<string>` could both be generalized to a `IParallelFunc<object>` and be handled by your method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But the problem is that I can't still add it to a List of type List<ParallelFunction<object>>.

Comment: jup. i'm on .net 4. it's not working with List<MyClass<object>>